# Проверка выделения памяти

Tags: c++, c

Вдруг задумался о том, что в коде я не делаю не одной проверки при выделении памяти на предмет ошибки выделения: то есть для malloc/new, или если это контейнеры, то .resize, .push_back, .shrink_to_fit  - вообще не делаю проверок, хотя теоретически нужно бы делать.

Интересно просто, насколько часто кто-то делает такие проверки -  отлавливает исключения или проверяет return`ы в таких случаях ?

Comment: Отсутствие проверки результата malloc или варианта new без исключений является грубой ошибкой. Ну а когда выбрасывается исключение - то ошибку проигнорировать не получится.

Comment: В программах типа "молоток" и "небоскреб", всегда. В "зубочистках", только если предполагаю, что может быть запрошено действительно много (сотни мегабайт) памяти. Впрочем, в Linux вы практически никогда не увидите, что памяти не хватает. До того момента, когда в процессе обращения к уже выделенной памяти ОС не обнаружит, что ее в самом деле не хватает (но и в этом случае, убит может быть и не истинный виновник, а тот, [кто не понравился системе](http://geckich.blogspot.com/2013/12/linux-out-of-memory-killer-oom.html))